# Implementing single sign on with gluu on reportserver

Tags: single-sign-on, reportserver, gluu

I need to enable SSO on a reportserver using gluu, but the documentation on enabling SSO on reportserver only talks about LDAP.

Does anyone have experience trying this?

I tried to search on the documentation, but only ldap is covered,not gluu.